# Ultra wide camera issue on iPhone 11 Pro

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I'm building a custom camera which I want to allow the user to switch between ultra-wide camera, wide camera and telephoto camera, just like the default camera app, but I've been facing some weird issue which I will try to show below:

[image: ios camera app]

[image: custom-camera-picture]

The first image was taken using the iOS default camera app and the second one was using my custom camera app. It seems to me that I'm not fitting my `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` correctly when I switch from the wide camera to the ultra-wide camera. The thing is: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do that, so can you guys give me a clue on how to solve it?

I also have a video which shows the transition between the cameras in my custom app, but I can't upload it here.

This is party of the code where I switch between the cameras:

```
if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInUltraWideCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
                    currentCameraDevice = device
                    changeCameraDevice()
                }
            }
```

```
    private func changeCameraDevice() {
        guard captureSession.isRunning else { return }
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        
        guard let view = (view as? UIViewController)?.view else { return }
        guard let device = currentCameraDevice else { return }
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) else { return }
        captureSession.inputs.forEach { captureSession.removeInput($0) }
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        captureSession.startRunning()
        viewDidLayoutSubviews(view)
    }
```

Here is where I insert the preview layer into the stack of layer of the view:

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: index)
```

where `layer` is the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue, so whoever stumbles on this question in the future. I was setting the `videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill`, but it doesn't work properly when the one uses the ultra wide camera. In order to fix it, all you have to do is to remove this line or set `videoGravity = .resizeAspect`